# is here anybody knows how to download and enable ngx_http_session_log_module?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

is here anybody knows how to download and enable ngx_http_session_log_module? i want to use this module to collect and analyze the detailed http session information on nginx server.  seems the nginx official website only introduced  the function and syntax of this module, not further links for module download and enable manipulatings:

[https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/nginx/current/reference/http-ngx_http_session_log_module.html#:~:text=The%20ngx_http_session_log_module%20module%20enables%20logging%20sessions%20%28that%20is%2C,is%20available%20as%20part%20of%20our%20commercial%20subscription](https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/nginx/current/reference/http-ngx_http_session_log_module.html#:%7E:text=The%20ngx_http_session_log_module%20module%20enables%20logging%20sessions%20%28that%20is%2C,is%20available%20as%20part%20of%20our%20commercial%20subscription).

i've spent several hours trying to find some cues from google searching, but unfortunately, no any useful information could help me to continue my works. anybody has the same experience?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part of `This module is available as part of our commercial subscription` is not clear...

Comment: yes, i also noticed this comments, so the ONLY way i could download and enable this module is to purchase its commercial subscription?